# Text Wrapping not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got this XAML code and I've been trying to get it working for a few hours now (I'm pretty new to WPF). I basically want the text in the `TextBlock` to line break if there's not enough room for it.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=imageurl}" Width="60" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" />
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=content}" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me, TextBlock wraps when window is resized to a smaller than required size to fit text. How is the Grid's parent structured? Try checking TextBlock size with http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to see if it's maybe expanded beyond window dimensions...

Comment: @Viv It seems like the second column's width is somehow wrong. If I set it to a fixed width, like "200", the code works fine. Seems like Im missing something. Maybe it has something to do with the code being a Data Template?..

Comment: well can you post your full xaml then. cant reproduce your problem with what you've posted, so not too sure what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, I basically set the Grid `ColumnDefinition` width to a fixed one and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely being caused by the parent giving the Grid infinite layout width, which causes "*" to give its column infinite layout width.  A likely culprit for this kind of behavior is an outer StackPanel (oriented horizontally) containing the Grid.  Other candidates include Viewbox, DockPanel or use in a ListBox (the default style for the ListBoxItem container object gives its content infinite layout width.)

You mentioned it is in a DataTemplate, which could suggest the last case.  If this is so, you can get the desired behavior by styling the generated container object so that it has HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".

```
        <ListBox Margin="3,0,3,3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```